# text mining python keys

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I have a multiline file, tab separated, which might include (or not) some keywords int the second column,

> Place1______________fish
>
> Place2______________fishing someting
>
> Placexx_____________something missing
>
> Place_somwhere______something else missing
>
> EHDN_______________fishing something
>
> HDGFE______________looking for something

(the lines are uggly but i couldn't manage to make the data look like a table)

I would need to, each time that the line contains 'something missing', to add an annotation at the end of the line, like "ACTION NEEDED THERE";

I've tried someting like:

```
pattern="something missing"
OUT=open('/Users/user/output.tab','w')

for line in file:
  field=line.split('\t')
  if pattern in field[1]:
    action = ';'.join("ACTION NEEDED")
    OUT.write(action.strip().replace('"',' '))
```

or findall re function without success...

Can you help me please ? Should re.findall work here ?
I've tried pattern=re.findall("something missing", line) but it's not working....
Sorry for asking that but i did not manage to find the right answer in the previous posts.....
Many Thanks in advance !

Comment: `something else missing` for this, do you want to add annotation?

Comment: yes, I have three or four different pattern to "recognize" in my second column ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this,

```
if pattern in field[1]:
```

to

```
if any([True for word in pattern.split() if word in line]):
```

You can add the annotation by,

```
line+" "+your_annotation
```